# Is it more intuitive to "show frozen/deleted rooms" based on the site that you're currently on?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, chat

As a moderator on Sports SE, I utilize chat often.

**TL;DR** Is it more intuitive to "show frozen/deleted rooms" based on the site that you're currently on given that upon entering chat, you are presented with a list of chat rooms based on said site? Currently, I am presented a list of chat rooms about The Stack Exchange network when I select "show frozen/deleted rooms"
after seeing a list of rooms based on the site I was on upon entering chat.

For a use-case, see below (This is sort of confusing, I know, but I hope I did well enough to explain myself).

---

By entering chat (SE dropdown > chat),

[image: Entering Chat]

I am presented with a list of chat rooms based on the site I'm currently on.

[image: Rooms of Sports SE]

Then, when I want to see frozen/deleted rooms, I get a list of rooms about The Stack Exchange Network.

[image: Rooms of SE Network]

---

However, when I change the room associated with "a list of rooms about" to Sports, I get the following.

[image: Rooms of Sports SE 2]

And when I want to see frozen/deleted rooms:

[image: Frozen/Deleted Rooms of Sports SE]

This is what I expected to see when I first tried to use "show frozen/deleted rooms," but was led to a list of rooms of The Stack Exchange Network. I understand why ("a list of rooms about The Stack Exchange Network"), but is it more intuitive to "show frozen/deleted rooms" about the site I'm currently on if that's what I see entering chat.